# can help me to solve ListView?

Tags: android

I am new in android. I dont know to list items in android? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Ask better questions... Also learn to except answers.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the "Notes" sample that comes with the toolkit. They fill `ListView`s from databases here. This gives you a first idea. Ask more specific questions then.